# Call DB2 stored proc with array parameter using ibm_db_dbi in Python

Tags: python, arrays, stored-procedures, db2

Is it possible to call a stored proc with ibm_db or ibm_db_dbi in python and pass array variables as parameters?

```
arr1 = ['a','b','c']
arr2 = ['x','y','z']

test = curDB2.callproc('subsystem.PYTHON_ARRAY_TEST',(arr1,arr2))
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
DatabaseError: ibm_db_dbi::DatabaseError: Describe Param Failed: [IBM][CLI 
Driver] CLI0150E  Driver not capable. SQLSTATE=HYC00 SQLCODE=-99999
```

The driver version that I am using is 10.01.200.238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ibm_db, ibm_db_dbi modules at current versions (2.0.9) do not support passing Python arrays to SQLPL stored procedures.

Don't know if the JayDeBeApi module supports it either.

You will need to either serialize the array or pass individual elements as separate parameters.

Note that ordinary Python dynamic arrays are not constrained to a specific type for each element (although you can use the array module to constrain the element type), but SQLPL arrays are constrained to a single type.

If you are proficient with 'C' language programming, IBM makes the source code for ibm_db/ibm_db_dbi available on github, and you can extend it to support passing typed arrays from Python to SQLPL procedures.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know if Python arrays may be passed to DB2 stored procedures using SQLalchemy and ibm_db_sa?